# Bash - how to use variable as command argument

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that runs the same SQL command on a batch of Hadoop tables of my choice.
I want to encapsulate the command into a function, so that I can print it to show the user what is exactly being run, while also feeding it to the beeline command that will execute it.

Now, my issue is that while the printout shows the correct command, the beeline execution fails miserably.

My code looks like this:

```
# Define a function that prints the command we intend to run in batch
SQL_OPERATION() {
  echo "'SELECT * FROM $1.$2 LIMIT 1;'"
}

    my_command=$(SQL_OPERATION ${TSCHEMA_SOURCE} ${TABLE_NAME} )
    echo "beeline --silent=false -e $my_command 2>&1"
    beeline --silent=false -e ${my_command} 2>&1
```

Now, the output of the `echo` command is flawless. If I copy and paste that on the terminal and run it manually, it does what it's supposed to do.

However, the script fails with beeline spitting out an error that implies it received an incorrect argument. To add to my confusion, the error log looks like the content of my `~` directory (literally, the output of `ls ~` ) has been fed to it. I cannot make sense of this.

Anyone can shed a light on this?
Thank you in advance!

The error I get:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in select clause (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'batchtableslist_2023' '-' '10' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'batchtableslist_2023' '-' '10' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'batchtableslist_2023' '-' '10' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'batchtableslist' '.' 'txt' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'git_commit' '.' 'txt' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'git_tree' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hadoop_logs' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'personal' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'public' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near '2023_comms' '.' 'csv' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'share' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'test_query' '.' 'txt' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'testquery' '.' 'txt' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:4 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in join source (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'atci' '.' 'utilization_check' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'LIMIT' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near '1' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Comment: Did you try escaping it with quotes?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Short summary: storing/passing commands as strings is absolutely full of traps for the unwary, and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: First, check your script with the shellcheck https://www.shellcheck.net and fix the quoting issues.

Comment: The files are not produced by `ls` but by expanding the `*` glob pattern embedded in `$my_command`.  See [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for information about glob patterns.  The fact that embedded glob patterns get expanded without quotes is one of the reasons why variable expansions should almost always be quoted (e.g. `"$my_command"`).  See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/4154375) and [Quotes - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: See what happens when you type `echo *` from the same directory you're running your script from. Voting to close as a typo. As mentioned above, lean to use shellcheck.net. Good luck.